# ¿Qué significa "DR" en este archivo de BAT?

Tags: batch

En el código de abajo hay un parámetro que se llama DR. Creo que R significa "Read-only file" (archivo de solo lectura), pero no tengo idea que significa D. ¿Qué significa "DR" en este código?

```
:: Deletes All files in the Current Directory With Prompts and Warnings 
::(Hidden, System, and Read-Only Files are Not Affected) 
:: 
@ECHO OFF 
DEL . 
DR
```

Comment: Este es un batch de Windows?

Comment: si, windows 7 home basic

Comment: Pues en la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc754340%28v%3dws.11%29) no aparece, así que más bien cuéntanos, de dónde salió ese archivo y qué se supone que debe hacer?

Comment: La verdad que el mundo de los codigos informaticos es  un mundo de mentiras y ocultamientos.... ese bloque de codigo lo extraje desde una pagina web que ense;asupuestamente a familiarizarse con el batch scripting de windowsOS y le encaja en su primer ejemplo esa sintaxis y ni siquiera explica cada argumento que significa solo resumen diciendo que Deletes All files in the Current Directory  osea deleta todos los archivos del directorio actual los  argumentos no explica yo tuve que adivinar practicamente pero no logre entender el D mayuscula que hace lo removi lo ejecute y no cambia nada relevan

Comment: De acuerdo, je. El borrado lo hace con `DEL .`, que es el comando pa borrar de toda la vida, referenciando el punto como la ubicación relativa a la carpeta donde se está ejecutando el script. Ese `DR` es el que no tenemos idea de dónde habrá salido...